# protractor : how can I run webdriver-manager update successfully?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

Trying to install the latest protractor but step 2 (www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) does not go as planned, got this error:

```
[12:08:38] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Users\bertie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com selenium-release.sto
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

I am behind a proxy on the network, don't know the proxy-name but have the pac file. What workaround can I use to get webdriver installed and running? using node version 6.11.2 and windows 2008R2.

Answer (score -1):

According to PAC proxy file [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config), PAC file includes a javascript function which will return the proxy address. You can try to find out the proxy address if you can't obtain it from your network admin.

[image]

Once you get proxy address, you can do as one of below two options:

1) pass proxy in webdriver-manager cli

```
webdriver-manager update/start --proxy proxy_address
```

2) Add `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` in Windows Environment Variable

Then you no need to pass-in proxy in cmd line every time.

Comment: Tried step 1 and got: (node:2292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: Invalid protocol: some.proxy:
(node:2292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): Error: Invalid protocol: some.proxy:
(node:2292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: Invalid protocol: some.proxy.

Comment: Did you add protocol ahead of the proxy address, for example `webdriver-manager update --proxy http://my.company.proxy.com:8000` and you can change the browser proxy setting to verify the proxy address can access internet before trying on webdriver-manage cmd

Comment: In addition to the --proxy flag, also add --gecko false. The webdriver-manager update does not work for gecko driver.